# Pattern-matching in Haskell and Erlang

Tags: haskell, erlang, pattern-matching

I have a small Erlang function that compares if two lists are equal:

```
myEq([], [])         -> true;
myEq([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) -> myEq(Xs, Ys);
myEq(_, _)           -> false.
```

The comparison takes place on line 2, the `X` of `[X|Xs]` always binds to the first element of the first list, the `[X|Ys]` matches only if the first elements of both lists are equal.

If I try this in Haskell I get an error message: "*Conflicting definitions for `x`*".
A possible solution in Haskell would be:

```
myEq (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == y then myEq xs ys else False
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to do this in Haskell using pattern matching?

Answer (score 11):

No, in Haskell you cannot use the same variable `x` in the head of a clause. Haskell does **not** do *unification* or *equality checks* like for instance respectively *Prolog* and *Erlang* do. This is specified in the [*Haskell '98*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.3.1) report:

> The set of patterns corresponding to each match must be linear---**no variable is allowed to appear more than once** in the entire set.

(copied, boldface added)

The only way to do it is using a guard (or any other type of checking in the body of course). You can however write it more elegant like:

```
myEq [] [] = True
myEq (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = myEq xs ys
--                 | otherwise = False
myEq _ _ = False
```

the `otherwise` case can be omitted since Haskell will fallback on the last clause and thus return `False`.

Or perhaps even more elegant:

```
myEq [] [] = True
myEq (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y && myEq xs ys
myEq _ _ = False
```

Personally I think that is better since here you state *explicitly* that `x` is equal to `y` so making mistakes like by accident writing the same variable cannot happen. Although of course it is a matter of taste.

Comment: To clarify: Erlang doesn't do unification either. If a variable occurs multiple times in a pattern, the Erlang compiler simply generates fresh names for the other occurrences and inserts a guard test that requires them to be equal, just like you'd do manually in Haskell.

Comment: @RichardC: I've rewrote the answer to *unification* and *equality checks*. Do you think this addresses this problem better?

Comment: Yes, that looks better.

Answer (score 1):

No. Every variable can be bound at most once on the pattern matching side. If you wanted to bind a variable twice you would have to evaluate to perform unification.